# Error in mybatis with spring when try to insert nulls

Tags: java, spring, oracle11g, mybatis

I am trying to execute this insert:

```
@Insert("" +
            "insert into EXTRANET.EX_ENTIDAD (ENT_REFNUM, ENT_TIPO, REG_PUB_ID, OFIC_REG_ID, AREA_REG_ID, " +
            "COD_LIBRO, NUM_PARTIDA, ANO_TITU, NUM_TITU, ENT_TRIGGER, TMSTMP_CREA, PRIORIDAD) " +
            " values (EXTRANET.EX_ENTIDAD_SEQ.nextval, #{entTipo}, " +
            "#{regPubId}, #{oficRegId}, #{areaRegId}, #{codLibro}, #{numPartida}, #{anoTitu}, " +
            " #{numTitu}, 'SYNC', SYSDATE, #{prioridad})")
    public int insertEntidades(Map map);
```

But if some #{param} is NULL I got it error:

Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting null for parameter #1 with JdbcType NULL . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different jdbcTypeForNull

I was searching some solution and read that I must to configure a property: jdbcTypeForNull

Then I update my configuration in Spring:

```
@Bean
public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception,Throwable  {
    SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    //sessionFactory.setConfigLocation( new ClassPathResource("gob.pe.sunarp.extranet.config.config.xml"));
    sessionFactory.setTypeAliasesPackage("gob.pe.sunarp.extranet.dao.beans");
    final Properties sqlSessionFactoryProperties = new Properties();
    sqlSessionFactoryProperties.put("jdbcTypeForNull", "NULL");
    sessionFactory.setConfigurationProperties(sqlSessionFactoryProperties );

    return sessionFactory;
}
```

But the error continues yet.

I found many solutions for xml but I use only java interfaces.
Some idea about this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [MyBatis documentation](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html)

> The JDBC Type is required by JDBC for all nullable columns, if null is passed as a value. You can investigate this yourself by reading the JavaDocs for the PreparedStatement.setNull() method.

Have you set the jdbcType for your parameters? For example:

```
#{property,javaType=int,jdbcType=NUMERIC}
```

Setting the jdbcTypeForNull may not work for your driver as indicated in the [documentation](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/configuration.html#ypeAliases).

> Specifies the JDBC type for null values when no specific JDBC type was provided for the parameter. Some drivers require specifying the column JDBC type but others work with generic values like NULL, VARCHAR or OTHER.

Comment: Hi @Centinul, I did a test:    @Insert("INSERT INTO JOEWEB.PRUEBA (ID, TEXTO) VALUES(#{id}, #{texto,jdbcType=VARCHAR})")
    public int insertPrueba(Map map);  and the insert finish successfully. But I have many statements in the project. Does exist a global configuration for give solution to this problem? If doesn't exist. What problem have in this week!! :(

Comment: @JoseDiazDiaz, what JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: I am using ojdbc6.jar. My Oracle is 11.2.0.2. The version of mybatis is 3.2.7, mybatis-spring 1.2.2, spring 4.0.6 in general. I have 500 statements. For this reason I am worried about this.

Comment: @JoseDiazDiaz I see that you've commented out your XML configuration. By chance have you tried to use the XML configuration and set that property there?

Comment: Yes, @Centinul. Both alternatives and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("entTipo", (Long) null);

insertEntidades(map);
```

Comment: I did the test @eddú-meléndez but nothing. For now only is running with #{texto,jdbcType=VARCHAR}.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a global setting..try something like this

in Java code

```
sqlSessionFactoryProperties.put("jdbcTypeForNull", JdbcType.DATE);
```

or in in mybatis-config.xml

```
<configuration>
    <settings>
        <setting name="jdbcTypeForNull" value="DATE" />             
    </settings>    
</configuration>
```

This way you are allowing insert/update for any DATE column.

I'd recommend using mybatis-config.xml solution to avoid issues with your Unit Tests